# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network request failed]

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, gql

I use `react-native` with `graphQL` and `expo`.

I keep facing this error issue.
This is caused when I try to `upload file` to back from front.

I don't know whether it is because of `network` issue or `code` issue.

ps - I use `localtunnel` to link back and front.

> npx localtunnel --port 4000

This issue has existed for more than a month :(

Please help me.

```
network Error [TypeError: Network request failed]
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/http:/172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/http:/172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network request failed]
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:174965:29 in ApolloError
at node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs:1120:40 in utilities.asyncMap.subscribe$argument_0.error
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169991:22 in onNotify
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169991:22 in onNotify
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
at node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs:968:4 in iterateObserversSafely
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169570:34 in error
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169991:22 in onNotify
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169991:22 in onNotify
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:176657:28 in error
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
at http://172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:169991:22 in onNotify
at node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
at node_modules/apollo-upload-client/public/createUploadLink.js:227:22 in runtimeFetch.then.then.then._catch$argument_0
```

--

this error message shows me some weird path:
`/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/http:/172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false`.

if I go to `/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native`, there's no 'http:/172.30~~' file.

[image]

**btw, this http:/172.30~~ path is my `expo address`.**

[image]

Comment: why use localtunnel ?

Comment: Did you checked this messsage? `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native/http:/172.30.1.35:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'` looks really weird this http://.... in this path.

Comment: @hongdeveloper - I use expo to run simulator on my phone. So I want to access DB from my phone easily thru localtunnel. that's localtunnel's purpose, isn't it?

Comment: @Gismo1337 = how can I check? I upload the photo on my post. in `/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-native`, there's no http://~~ file. btw this http address is my expo address. check my post. thanks for your reply

Comment: Using tunnel is to share this expo with others. there is no need for a tunnel to access databases. https://docs.expo.dev/development/development-workflows/#tunnel-urls

Comment: @Gismo1337- ok thanks. I change link from localtunnel to `localhost`. but still same error -> `const uploadHttpLink = createUploadLink({uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql", });`

Comment: @hyejung Register through the internal ip, not the localhost. Also, make sure that the output rule and input rule of the port are allowed.

Comment: @hongdeveloper - thanks it seems solved